# Scanner doesn't return correct result?

Tags: java

I'm currently making a Hi-Lo card game as a programming assignment.
My code to detect whether the user wants to guess higher, lower or equal is below.

```
DeckOfCards deck = new DeckOfCards(); 
PlayingCard card = deck.deal(); 
PlayingCard next = deck.deal(); 
System.out.println("Welcome to the High Low Card Game.\n" +
                   "You're current card is: "+card.toPictograph() + 
                   ". Will the Next card be higher/lower/equal "+
                   "to the current card?\nType Quit to exit.");
Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
if(inputScanner.hasNext("higher")){

        System.out.println("Congradulations you won");
        wins++;
}
 else if (inputScanner.hasNext("lower"))
 {
     System.out.println("You suck");
 }
 else if (inputScanner.hasNext("equal"))
 {
     System.out.println("You suck");
 }
```

If I type in 'higher', 'lower' or 'equal' (without the ' ') the program does nothing.
Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Read the line into a variable and operate on the variable instead.

Comment: I assume that this is not the first `Scanner` you're using in your project? The problem is, that you call `#hasNext(String)`, but never `#next()`, therefore you never actually read something from the input stream. That means that `#hasNext(String)` always evaluates the very first input of the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You better save the inserted token into a `String` variable and then compare it to whatever you want.

`.next()` will only save your first word. If you want to save a whole line (including spaces), use `.nextLine()`

```
DeckOfCards deck = new DeckOfCards(); 
PlayingCard card = deck.deal(); 
PlayingCard next = deck.deal(); 
System.out.println("Welcome to the High Low Card Game.\nYou're current card is: "+card.toPictograph()+". Will the Next card be higher/lower/equal to the current card?\nType Quit to exit.");
Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = inputScanner.next();
if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("higher"))
{
    System.out.println("Congradulations you won");
    wins++;
}
else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("lower"))
{
    System.out.println("You suck");
}
else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("equal"))
{
    System.out.println("You suck");
}
```